# How to check if any model item is assigned a value in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a model which have properties.And, i want to check that if any model item has some value or not.Also,no property is set to mandatory or optional using data-annotations.If no property is assigned and any value then i should set some model error e.g "**Please specify some search criteria.**"

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetAdvanceSearchData", "Home", FormMethod.Post)){     
<div class="rTableCell" style="border:none !important">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MessageStatus, new { placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.MessageStatus), @class = "fieldtextbox", @style = "height: 25px !important" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MessageStatus)
            </div>
            <div class="rTableCell" style="border:none !important">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RequestType, new { placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(n => n.RequestType), @class = "fieldtextbox", @style = "height: 25px !important" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.RequestType)
            </div>
            <div class="rTableCell" style="border:none !important">
            </div>
            <div class="rTableCell" style="border:none !important">
                <p class="submit">
                    <button type="submit" name="submit">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
}
```

These are only few properties for the model.

Comment: Please add your code and [mcve] of the problem.

Comment: You want to do it client or server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In action method `GetAdvanceSearchData` you can do your own validity checks, in addition to validation attributes, or instead of them.

If you add an entry to `ModelState` then `ModelState.IsValid` will become false, and the added entry will show in the output of `Html.ValidationMessageFor(...)` or `Html.ValidationSummary()`.

Example:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetAdvanceSearchData(YourModel vm)
{
    if (vm == null || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.MessageStatus) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(vm.RequestType)))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please specify some search criteria")
        // Using "" as Key will only show when you use @Html.ValidationSummary().
        // Using "myErr" as Key will show when you use @Html.ValidationMessage("myErr").
        // Using a property name as Key will show it next to the property if you use @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.property).
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var results = ...
        return View("ResultsView", results);
    }
    else
    {
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```